# Why do I get a TextFieldConfiguration?

Tags: flutter

Why this is not working :

FormBuilderTypeAhead(
textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(autofocus: true),

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add more information (error message, clear question, more code) for this to be answerable.

Comment: Here is the error : The method 'TextFieldConfiguration' isn't defined for the type 'PlacesAutocomplete'. Thanks

Comment: `TextFieldConfiguration` seems to be coming from here: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_typeahead/1.9.3/flutter_typeahead/TextFieldConfiguration-class.html. Are you sure you are importing this package/class correctly?

Comment: I use this one : https://pub.dev/packages/map_location_picker and everything is working well excepting this textFieldConfiguration :/

Comment: It depends on `flutter_typeahead` transitively, so you should be able to import it, specifcally this class: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_typeahead/1.9.3/flutter_typeahead/TextFieldConfiguration-class.html

Comment: I'll add this as an answer and you can accept it later so other people can find this as well.

Comment: Just I got this now, do you have any idea why ? "Depend on referenced packages." ?

Comment: You are using classes from packages which are only transitively referenced by a package you added to your pubspec.yaml (in your case: map_location_picker). You either need to avoid using those classes or add those dependencies to your project with "flutter pub add`. I guess you probably want to use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/form_builder_extra_fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextFieldConfiguration` belongs to the package `flutter_typeahead` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead). You need to import it in your code, specifcially https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_typeahead/1.9.3/flutter_typeahead/TextFieldConfiguration-class.html

```
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';
```